# Date Range over different years and months

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, date-range

Hi I have a assignment from college to do with staff holidays I have to output the holidays in the equivalent month and year.

Test data: 
    jon smith start date 28.12.2015 end date 2.1.2016

I can output using the 
    start date: 2015 December, john Smith 28.12.2015 ending 2.1.2016

but I also need this data to be in

```
2016 January john smith 28.12.2015 ending 2.1.2016
```

because the holiday start in Dec 2015 and end in Jan 2016,

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datestart, '%M') as month,
               DATE_FORMAT(dateEnd, '%M') as monthe,
               MONTH(datestart) AS m,
               MONTH(dateEnd) AS e,YEAR(datestart) AS year,
               holiday.Id, employeeId, datestart,dateEnd,   
               DATE_FORMAT(holiday.dateEnd,'%D %M, %Y') AS end,        
               DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%D %M, %Y') AS startit, 
               CONCAT(employees.empFirst,' ',employees.empLast) AS employee,
                DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS start From holiday
        LEFT JOIN employees ON holiday.employeeId = employees.empId ORDER BY datestart ";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$result1 = $mysqli->query($sql);
$year = array();
$monthx = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 
                'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 
                'November', 'December'); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $year = $row['year'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    $monthe = $row['monthe'];
    $years[$year][$month][] = $row;
    //print_r($something);
}

foreach($years as $year => $months)  {
    echo '<b>Year &nbsp;'.$year. '</b><br>';

    foreach ($monthx as $month) {
        echo '<b>'.$month. '</b><br>';
        if (isset($months[$month]))
        {
            foreach($months[$month] as $item) {
                echo $item['employee']. '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' .$item['startit'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$item['end'].'<br/>';
             }
         }else{ 
            echo 'No Holidays Booked<br/>';
         }
    }
}
```

How do I incorporate the end date so a holiday spread  over eg. start date 28.12.2015 end date 2.1.2016 will be in each of the required year and month.

Comment: You are not really doing much of this homework yourself are you!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly OK I get your point. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there are lots of clear and simple writeups available on date processing in databases.  There's the PDF of Prof. Snodgrass's terrific book. It's plenty clear, but not simple.  http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html

What you have is two date ranges:  a: astart - aend   and   b: bstart - bend.

If you want to know if b is a proper subset of a, the logic is this:

```
 bstart >= astart   AND   bend <= aend
```

If you want to know if b and a do not overlap at all, the logic is this

```
bstart > aend  OR astart > bend
```

Then, you simply need good old SQL date arithmetic ....

```
 WHERE holiday.start >= person.start /* holiday subset of person dates */ 
   AND holiday.start <= person.end
```

And, if the person's range overlaps the holiday range,

```
 WHERE NOT (holiday.start > person.end OR person.start > holiday.end)
```